# how to control opacity of descendant controls based on parent control's opacity ?

Tags: wpf, xaml, opacity

I have created a user control having grid and few controls inside grid. I have set Opacity to .1 of my parent grid and i want to set the descendant control's opacity to 1. Is is possible to do in XAML tree architecture ? 
Here is my xaml code:

```
<Grid Name="busyIndicatorGrid" Visibility="Visible" Opacity=".2"
      Background="DarkBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Opacity="1" 
                Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ProgressBar Name="progressBar" Foreground="White" 
                     IsIndeterminate="True" MinWidth="100" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Name="txtProgressText" 
                   FontSize="40" 
                   Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                   Text="Please wait while application is being initialized."
                   TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the valuable suggestions. But i have found way to resolve my issue by using brush for the parent grid control.

```
<Grid Name="busyIndicatorGrid" Visibility="Visible" Opacity=".2"
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="DarkBlue" Opacity="0.2"/>
    </Grid.Background>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
            Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ProgressBar Name="progressBar" Foreground="White" 
                 IsIndeterminate="True" MinWidth="100" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Name="txtProgressText" 
               FontSize="40" 
               Margin="0,5,0,0" 
               Text="Please wait while application is being initialized."
               TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</StackPanel>
```

By doing so it will draw parent grid with the opacity i have defined in background property and it will have no effect on inside controls. all the controls will be drawn as usual without any opacity overriding effect which was set on parent grid.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is a property that will be propagated down the subtree.

If parent opacity is 0.5 and child opacity is 0.2 the parent will be drawn with 50% and child will be drawn with 20% of parent's 50%... Sort of like that just for better understanding... I hope you get me :)

Try this out and you will see:

```
<Grid Name="busyIndicatorGrid" Visibility="Visible" Opacity=".2">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Opacity="1" >
     ...

<Grid Name="busyIndicatorGrid" Visibility="Visible" Opacity=".2">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Opacity="0.5">
    ...
```

Those two will be drawn differently that means the children do no take the opacity value from its parent but instead calculate their own.

If you want to control how inner children are going to be drawn I would suggest to you to create an attached property that inherits its content down the VisualTree and when set to true it changes the opacity of its "underneathly" associated elements to 1 or to their previous old value.

Here is an example:

```
    public static bool GetChangeOpacity(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ChangeOpacityProperty);
    }

    public static void SetChangeOpacity(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ChangeOpacityProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ChangeOpacity.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChangeOpacityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ChangeOpacity", typeof(bool), typeof(YourClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null && (bool)args.NewValue)
        {
            fe.Tag = fe.Opacity;
            fe.Opacity = 1;
        }
        else if(fe != null && fe.Tag != null)
        {
            fe.Opacity = (double)fe.Tag;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation :) Could you please add the code snippet of what you explained ?

Comment: I just did. Take a look at it.

Comment: I tried using attached behavior as u said, but i don't see any changes its like i am setting inner controls opacity to 1 when my behavior is set to true but problem still persists. Parent Grid control's Opacity is set to .2 and i want to see the inner controls fully visible without any opacity applied.

Comment: Read this again **If parent opacity is 0.5 and child opacity is 0.2 the parent will be drawn with 50% and child will be drawn with 20% of parent's 50%...** Child will always take parent opacity in its drawin calculations. You should consider changing opacity on color if you want to change color to be less as strong but not on complete control.